# Problema com inserção em banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Tenho no meu sistema o seguinte código:

```
    public int insert_dependente(Dependente dependente) {
    ResultSet r;
    int result = 0;
    if (!(dependente == null)) {
        try {
            Connection conn = new Conexao().getConnection();
            String sql = "insert into Dependente "
                    + "(IdAssoc,"
                    + "NomeDep,"
                    + "SobrenomeDep,"
                    + "RgDep,"
                    + "CpfDep,"
                    + " DtNascDep,"
                    + " emailDep,"
                    + " tipoDep,"
                    + " DtCriacaoDep)"
                    + " VALUES (" + dependente.getAssociado() + ","
                    + "'" + dependente.getNome() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getSobrenome() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getRg() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getCpf() + "',"
                    //+ new java.sql.Date(dependente.getNascimento().getTime()).toString() + ","
                    + "'" + dependente.getEmail() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getTipoDep() + "'";
                    //+ new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()).toString() + ")";
            Statement state; 
            state = conn.createStatement();
            state.execute(sql);
            state.close();

            String sql2 = "SELECT IdDep FROM Dependente WHERE CpfDep = " + dependente.getCpf();
            state = conn.createStatement();
            r = state.executeQuery(sql2);
            while (r.next()) {
                result = r.getInt("idDep");
            }
            r.close();
            state.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DependenteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

O meu problema é que quando o sistema chega na linha

```
state.execute(sql);
```

O código não é executado em meu banco de dados, e logo em seguida o sistema pula direto para a linha

```
return result;
```

Já tentei de tudo mas não consigo achar onde está meu erro.
Alguém tem uma idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: Se está indo para o retorno é por que alguma exceção é lançada, não? O que está sendo escrito no log?

Comment: Eu cheguei a olhar no log para ver se tinha alguma Exception, mas o o apache não acusa nenhuma.

Comment: Colocou um *breakpoint* no *catch* para conseguir acompanhar e ver qual é a exceção?

Comment: Configure o log na sua aplicação pois com certeza uma exceção está sendo lançada, como os coloegas mencionaram. Sem essa exceção fica difícil saber o problema. Ele pode ser por dados inconsistentes, alguma coluna ou tabela com nomes errados e assim por diante.

Comment: @RaphaelRosa pelas duas linhas comentadas é provável que está dando erro, uma vez que gera um *statement* inválido. Não testei, mas tente descomentar as linhas e testar novamente ou, continuando erro, aí sim informe na sua questão o erro.

Comment: Por favor, leia isso: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injeção_de_SQL e depois dê uma olhada nisso: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código tem vários problemas. O primeiro deles é que ao comentar os campos de datas na primeira SQL, ela ficou mal-formada. Ela espera 9 campos no `INSERT`, mas você só passa 7. Além disso ficou faltando um fecha-parênteses na SQL, uma vez que ele foi comentado junto com a última data.

Depois, use o [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) para evitar problemas de [injeção de SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL):

[image: XKCD]

Terceiro, use a [sintaxe do *try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Quarto, isso só vai funcionar se você tiver o *logging* configurado adequadamente:

```
Logger.getLogger(DependenteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Como provavelmente isso foi gerado automaticamente, acredito que você não deverá ter um *logging* apropriado, então é melhor ou configurar o *logging* ou trocar por algo mais simples como um `printStackTrace()`, ou relançar a exceção ou fazer algum tratamento de erro. Decidi usar no código abaixo o `printStackTrace()`.

Com isso, o seu código fica desse jeito:

```
public int insertDependente(Dependente dependente) {
    if (dependente == null) return 0;
    try (Connection conn = new Conexao().getConnection()) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Dependente (IdAssoc, NomeDep, SobrenomeDep, RgDep, CpfDep, DtNascDep, emailDep, tipoDep, DtCriacaoDep) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try (PreparedStatement state = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            state.setInt(1, dependente.getAssociado());
            state.setString(2, dependente.getNome());
            state.setString(3, dependente.getSobrenome());
            state.setString(4, dependente.getRg());
            state.setString(5, dependente.getCpf());
            state.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(dependente.getNascimento().getTime()));
            state.setString(7, dependente.getEmail());
            state.setString(8, dependente.getTipoDep());
            state.setDate(9, new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
            state.execute();
        }

        String sql2 = "SELECT IdDep FROM Dependente WHERE CpfDep = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement state = conn.prepareStatement(sql2)) {
            state.setInt(1, dependente.getCpf());
            try (ResultSet r = state.executeQuery()) {
                int result = 0;
                while (r.next()) {
                    result = r.getInt("idDep");
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```